# JavaScript link to another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the next code:

```
<p>
    <img alt="" src="imagini/slide1.png" 
         style="height: 64px; width: 64px" id="imgClickAndChange"
         onclick="changeImage()" />
</p>


<script language="javascript">
function changeImage() {

    if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "imagini/slide1.png") 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "imagini/platform.png";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "imagini/platform.png";
    }
}

</script>
```

That is changing an image (phase 1) after clicking on it into another image(phase 2). I want to link the second image (phase 2) to an index.php page. How do I do that? Is there a way of altering or interfering in the changeImage function.

Comment: You want the click on which image to link somewhere else? `slide1.png?` or clicks on `platform.png`?

Comment: to link somewhere else

Answer (score 2):

Use the `else` block of the `if` statement you already have to change `window.location`.

```
function changeImage() {

    if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src.indexOf("imagini/slide1.png") !== -1) {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "imagini/platform.png";
    } else {
         window.location = "index.php";
    }
}
```

Comment: it goes to the desired index.php but the second image doesn't appear.

Comment: Change the `==` to an `indexOf`. I edited my code to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to easily attach a click event on the second image only. Or you could have 2 images in the page (one alone and one inside a link) and then hide and show one image or another.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var myEl = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
var parent = myEl.parentNode();
var link = document.createElement('a');

link.href = 'http://www.google.com';
link.appendChild(myEl);

parent.removeChild(myEl);
myEl.src = "imagini/platform.png";
parent.appendChild(link);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function changeImage() {

   if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "imagini/slide1.png") 
   {
    document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "imagini/platform.png";
   }
   else 
   {
    document.location.href="index.php";
   }
}
```

Comment: it goes to the desired index.html but the second image doesn't appear